# How to give partition C full administrative right from a command line

Tags: windows-xp

I was playing with sharing rights on another computer with partition C. Something has gone wrong, because when I run my system i get "Access denied" message when trying to read C content. however:

- I was able to run system
- In total commander I get type: cd c:\program files and .. I am in ...

Something I have messed up ..

Can anyone tell me how to fix rights?

Answer (score 1):

Already found:

cacls c:\ /G Administrators:F

did the trick.

Thanks!